# Setting %PATH% for a service?

Tags: service, environment-variables, windows-xp

I have a service which is installed that runs and executes certain commands periodically. It runs as the Local System account. The source code for the service is not under my control, but I do control the Windows XP SP3 box that the service is on.

Recently, changes were made to the system that put a certain path at the forefront of the %PATH% for this service. One of the executables in that path has the same name as one of the commands my service uses, so the service mistakenly uses the wrong executable.

I need to change things back so that my service executes the right command. How do I modify the %PATH% so that the service will see it? I've already tried `setx -m ...` but with no luck.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The offending directory is specified either in the system-wide `PATH` environment variable, or in the Local System user's personal environment variables.

The Local System user's personal environment variables are specified at `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Environment`. The machine-wide environment variables are specified at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment`. The former isn't really easily accessible from anywhere except the registry, but the latter is accessible from the *Environment Variables* dialog on the *Advanced* tab of the *System Properties*.

Comment: Such PATH items appear to be appended at the end of the system-wide ones.